# How to find the amount of time a process spends in user mode or kernel mode

Tags: linux, kernel, proc, user-mode-linux

I read through the docs for cat /proc/pid/stat It displays many numbers.
The process I am calculating this for is running in an infinite loop. So the values will keep on changing. I see that there is something called utime and stime
I am not sure if these give the exact user time and kernel time for the running process?
Also is there a way to just extract these two numbers from the output rather than manually determining which number corresponds to utime and stime?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those fields give the exact user time and kernel time for the running process; [`man 5 proc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) describes them as

> Amount of time that this process has been scheduled
> in user mode, measured in clock ticks (divide by
> `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)`).  This includes guest time,
> guest_time (time spent running a virtual CPU, see
> below), so that applications that are not aware of
> the guest time field do not lose that time from
> their calculations.

and

> Amount of time that this process has been scheduled
> in kernel mode, measured in clock ticks (divide by
> `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)`).

respectively. (Guest time is field 43.)

You can extract them with any field-based tool, *e.g.*

```
awk '{print $14, $15}' /proc/$$/stat
```